created template for blog article doesn't take css file
Currently I'm working on a project to create my first blog website. Therefore I created my website with HTML and CSS and implemented everything with Eleventy so I can put my webpage into a CMS for easier administration. So far everything is working fine, but now I'm at a point where I wanted to create my template for the article pages.
This is what I have so far:
article.njk
---
layout: 'base.njk'
cssFile: 'post.css'
---
<article class="main-article">

    <div class="article-head">
        <div class="article-head-left">
            <h1 class="article-title">{{ title }}</h2>
            <h2 class="article-subheader">{{ description }}</h2>
            <span class="article-author"><a href="#">{{ author }}</a>{{ author-description }}</span>
            <time class="publication-time">{{ date }}</time>
        </div>
        <div class="article-head-right">
            <figure class="main-article-figure">
                <img src="{{ image }}" alt="{{ imageAlt }}">
                <figcaption>{{ imageAlt }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

    {{ content | safe }}

</article>

.eleventy.js
const {DateTime } = require("luxon");

module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
    
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('./src/css/public-css/reset.css');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('./src/css/public-css/main.css');
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('./src/assets')
    
    eleventyConfig.addFilter("postDate", (dateObj) => { return DateTime.fromJSDate(dateObj).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_MED);
})

    return {
      dir: {
        input: "src",
        output: "public"
      }
    }
  };

base.njk
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/public-css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/public-css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/page-css/{{ cssFile }}" />
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'header.njk' %}
    <main>
        {{ content | safe }}
    </main>
    {% include 'footer.njk' %}
</body>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f40fa953b8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>

With my index page and my blog page the CSS code <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/page-css/{{ cssFile }}" /> is working just fine. Only with my article pages it doesn't work.
I don't know what I did wrong and I'm kinda stuck.
Can anybody please help me?
Thank you!
EDITED!
This is what my article markdown file looks like:
2024-04-05-new-article.md
---
title: New Article
author: Phillipp Dittloff
author-description: founder of the blog PaperJourney.
date: 2024-04-05
image: /assets/img/br-misery-stephen-king.jpeg
imageAlt: Misery by Stephen King | Assets from www.google.com
description: Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt qui similique tenetur corrupti culpa deleniti consequatur voluptatem at quis, ipsum accusamus voluptatibus aliquid laborum veniam et illum dolorem voluptatum iusto.
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae at obcaecati unde debitis nihil labore dolorum, exercitationem excepturi sequi temporibus iusto. Asperiores quaerat quos ipsum aspernatur tempora accusantium alias saepe! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde in debitis id deserunt doloremque facere, voluptas modi perferendis fuga nobis enim sint nostrum error voluptatem libero magni ipsum placeat dolorum? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores voluptate nesciunt inventore maxime quod delectus. Nesciunt saepe quae perferendis voluptatibus, rerum velit ipsam? Repudiandae obcaecati error magnam, laborum minima asperiores.

Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et voluptate, possimus reprehenderit dolorem fugiat at aliquid vel corporis aspernatur sunt veniam explicabo expedita quae assumenda illo fuga similique! Qui, natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus adipisci et, distinctio porro deleniti qui dolorem, nam nobis sapiente repellat quod quo ab ea voluptatibus aut, delectus sed est iure?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi id quod iusto impedit quasi ipsam dignissimos explicabo dicta dolores minus eveniet, ullam adipisci consequatur molestias rem laborum saepe harum pariatur? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde dicta quasi officiis quo repellendus voluptatem quidem deleniti illo quos eveniet est tempore amet, molestias optio ullam consequatur dignissimos voluptatibus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere alias veniam qui veritatis accusantium dignissimos fugiat ipsam! Ut saepe, asperiores corrupti animi fugit exercitationem ullam eligendi, aliquam tempore quas repellat? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae cumque tenetur amet, excepturi modi dolorum quam ad voluptatum aperiam asperiores mollitia unde accusantium officia impedit vel velit officiis minus. Mollitia?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae cum accusantium debitis autem tenetur vitae saepe! Accusamus omnis illum aperiam iure voluptate laudantium, aliquam cum distinctio possimus quisquam voluptatum? Sequi.


It seems like there is no addPassthroughFileCopy for your page-css folder, so the file does not land inside your public build folder, you copy "css/public-css" but not "css/page-css"

Thanks for the fast reply! I tried adding an addPassthroughFileCopy too, but it's doing nothing. I also checked my public folder and my page-css files landed within it. My other pages are shown just fine. It's my markdown files I have trouble with.

I have tested your code in a new 11ty setup and it is working just fine, except the "author-description", because of the "-". I would change that to "author.name" and "author.description" (you have to adjust how you set it as well then)
Is eleventy giving you any compile errors in the console?

My index.njk und my blog.njk work fine. I think my problem is that my article pages I generate with my article.njk are markdown files. I edited my post so you can see what my markdown files look like.
To make it easier. I added my repository to my Github page.
The link is https://github.com/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney

Where do you set article.njk as the layout for the posts? I can not see it inside the fronmatter of your md post.

Okay, my repository is now up-to-date correctly. Had some struggle updating it. There is my complete file structure with all files inside. I have set the base.njk as my layout for the article.njk and added a cssFile: post.css to apply the file to it.

There's no .eleventy.js file. Anyway, if I add the eleventy file from your post to the repo it is broken indeed. But it is because your paths inside the link statements of , change ../ to just / and it will work.

the .eleventy.js file is now added. Sorry for the inconvenience. It didn't fully upload the files.

I was able to try it out and it worked! Thank you very much!

Okay I unfortunately have a follow up question. The way you told me worked perfectly with the formatting, but I can't adjust my settings in the 'post.css' file. It won't effect anything. Is there something I'm missing?

If your changes to the CSS file do not take effect I would assume something is wrong with the passthrough copy. Check your public folder and check the post.css file if it contains the most recent changes

I've checked the public folder and you're right. It's not getting pushed through to my public folder.

Make sure the addPassthroughFileCopy in your .eleventy.js file works, something seems wrong there, double check paths. eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('/src/css/page-css/{{ cssFile }}'); is wrong. {{ ccFile }} has nothing to do here. Try using this as a path instead /src/css/page-css, it should copy all files from page-css

It changed it but I could not see any effect on the change. It will not push the changes into the public folder after saving them in the src folder.

I could make it work. The issue was that eleventy is not recognizing CSS as a template extension in Eleventy I had to set the template formate so it's recognizing it and pushes it into the public folder. Now my only problem is to find out a way to formate the written text in the articles since it's plain text and not nested in elements like 
